# ASP MVC 3: Authentication lost sometimes in production

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

I am developing a web app using MVC 3 that is using standard form authentication. It is hosted on a shared hosting. The problem is that sometimes the user authentication state is lost. I get no exception at all. Do you have any clue what can be the cause?

Does authentication has anything to do with session? I am not using Session object at all.
I was of the impression that Authentication using cookie can work in a load balanced environment. Am I wrong?

The session is lost before the 20 minutes timespan.

Comment: That's not much to go on. Perhaps the app pool is recycling for some reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of things come to mind here:

1. Is there any pattern to the lost authentications?  Meaning, is it always after 20 minutes or is it really seemingly random?
2. Since you are on shared hosting, do you explictly set your machine keys in your web.config?  If you do not and they are set to auto generate, the keys will be different if your application is load balanced.  Thus you authenticate on server A and some subsequent request goes to server B, your application will not be able to decode the authorization cookie and 'kick you out'

> In a Web farm, you cannot guarantee which server will handle
>   successive requests. If a user is authenticated on one server and the
>   next request goes to another server, the authentication ticket will
>   fail the validation and require the user to re-authenticate. The
>   validationKey and decryptionKey attributes in the machineKey element
>   are used for hashing and encryption of the forms authentication
>   ticket. The default value for these attributes is
>   AutoGenerate.IsolateApps. The keys are auto-generated for each
>   application, and they are different on each server. Therefore,
>   authentication tickets that are encrypted on one computer cannot be
>   decrypted and verified on another computer in a Web farm, or in
>   another application on the same Web server. To address this issue, the
>   validationKey and decryptionKey values must be identical on all
>   computers in the Web farm.

See [here for more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx#pagexplained0002_webfarmscenarios) on that second bit.

Comment: thanks a lot. I set the machine key now and it works fine. You saved my day :)

Comment: @Tommy: "In a Web farm, you cannot guarantee which server will handle successive requests." - Wouldn't sticky sessions be an option here
?

Comment: @ShaiCohen - Sessions are independent of the forms authentication mechanism as the authorization stuff is placed in an encrypted authentication cookie (or in the URL if using cookieless).  For the OP's problem, not having a encrypt/decrypt key that is the same across multiple machines was preventing his app from decoding the auth cookies.

Answer (score 0):

The session has a time out, if you go past it your session (and authentication) will get destroyed.

You could increase its timeout from `web.config` or, and this is the way I went, you could make a dummy page you ping with AJAX every few min. The advantage of the latter is that your session will still terminate in a timely enough manner when the user closes his browser, as opposed to staying there for half an hour using resources and preventing `Application_OnExit` from running.

Comment: Does authentication has something to do with session? I am not using Session object at all.

Comment: Your authentication ID is held in the session object, yes.

Comment: Nope - session and forms authentication are mutually exclusive.  Your auth information is typically stored in an encrypted cookie which is passed with each request to/from your app.  See here for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx