# Users are logged out randomly from the application (after implemented 2FA)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api, session-cookies, multi-factor-authentication

I have a strange situation in the live environment and it is imposible to figure out what is the issue.
The users complain about the fact they are logged out after a random time.
On the client side it is an ASP MVC application that runs in IIS. Regarding the server side, it is and .net WebApi application that also runs in IIS. This is the session settings from web.config file of the client app:
`<sessionState cookieless="false" mode="InProc" timeout="120" />`
Even if I have set 120 minutes in config or in IIS advanced settings, they got the logout.
I have a recycle process set at 01:00 in the middle of the night. I have checked the logs files from EvenViewer and there are no other recycle processes trigered, only that one from the middle of the night.

The idea is that I can't reproduce it on my local machine. It happens at any time during the 120 minutes that are configured.

Few weeks ago, I have implemented a mechanism for 2FA using the following library:  https://github.com/RobThree/TwoFactorAuth.Net and a functionality "Trust this browser for the next 30 days" in order to skip the MFA authentication if the user want this. Actually, I just keep and expiration date in a cookie in order to know when should I reset the option and ask again the user for a new authentication code. Don't know if it is related to this, but they told me that they encountered this situation after I released that 2FA implementation.

**UPDATE** After I read more articles in order so solve this issue, I want to add that the aplication is hosted in AZURE. Maybe this information helps.

**UPDATE** Advanced settings from IIS
[image]

**UPDATE** This are session state settings
[image]

Any suggestions would help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you set a machine key in your web.config?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/10179568/130387

Comment: Also, SessionState and the authentication cookie are two different things. Your web.config should also have a section for authorization settings, that is where you would need to adjust authentication time out.  How long does the authorization cookie say its good for when you inspect it in your browser debug tools?  Lastly, since I am not familiar with this library, if it does indeed rely on sessions, you may want to implement a more robust session provider than InProc (SQL for instance).  InProc (memory) sessions are killed if the process restarts for any reason.

Comment: @Tommy Thanks for your answers. Regarding to your first one, as I understand the machine keys are related to web farms and load balancer, but I don't have anything like that. If you are referring to .ASPXAUTH it expires "When the browsing session ends". For ASP.NET_SessionId is the same.

Comment: you could try to store the session in a database and increase the iis idle time value. if possible disable iis application pool recycling.

Comment: @Jalpa Panchal, thanks for your answer. The iis application pool recycling is triggered only one time per day in the middle of the night. Can't be the caused.

Comment: @dumitrualin have you tried to increase idle time out. is it possible for you to store the session in databse?

Comment: @Jalpa Panchal, thanks for your answer. The idle time out is set to 20. No, I can't store it in database. I will attach the advance settings from IIS to the initial post.

Comment: Would it be a conflict if the session state timeout is set to 120 and the idle timeout is set to 20 and not requests to the the application. So, let's say we have 3 users: user A, user B and User C. User A is the first to log in the application, then user B and C. None of the users take any action in the application for 20 minutes. Because of that the idle timeout is trigered and the worker process will be shut down. So in this situation, will be logged out all the user? Just I am trying to identify if the idle timeout is the cause for the randomly logout of the users. Any idea?

Comment: You could set the application pool idle time out by more than 20 minutes. check the event viewer application, system, and security logs for more error details and provide us here.

Comment: @dalin, Were you able to solve this issue ? I am having the same issue. Random users get redirected to login page. It's not IIS pool recycle otherwise all of users will be redirected. I have set session timeout to 480. Any help would be appreciated.